# Explanation of equation

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

`Excel` gave this equation based on my chart. Since i am not expert on math; i could not understand it. And none of online math solver web sites did not recognize equation. I think there is something wrong with syntax or order.

```
 y = 14,122ln(x) + 32,022
```

I have `y` values, and need to find `x`. [possible y values are `10,30 and 60`]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $y = 14,122 \ln(x) + 32,022$ we get

$x=\exp(\frac{y-32,022}{14,122})$.

For example you get with $y=30$:

$x=1,15393...$

Answer (score 1):

If you look up natural logarithms, you'll find a whole plethora of material out there.

Specifically, you'll find that $\ln{x}$ and $\exp{x}$ are inverses of each other, which will help you solve your problem

Hint: 
$y = ln(x)$

has the solution (for real, positive values of $x$)

$x = \exp(y)$